# Elminating global variable + variable being used by two functions?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to eliminate global variables. Specifically the `var audio = document.createElement('audio')`

I used closures and immediately invoked functions. From what I remember, I think in that case, the outer function's variables are saved to memory?

I'm kinda confused about how I would use the audio variable in the second function. I have a vague idea that when `playSound()` is invoked in another part of the code. It should have a callback function as a parameter?

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

```
const playSound = (() => {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    return function () {
        audio.src = 'sounds/alarm.mp3'
        audio.loop = true;
        audio.play();
    }
})();

const resetter = (() => {
    var resetting = document.getElementById("reset");
    return resetting.addEventListener('click', function () {
        audio.pause();
        audio.loop = false;
        totalShadow.style.display = "none";
        totalShadow.querySelector('.match').style.display = 'none';
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only a single IIFE and define `audio` inside that:

```
const { playSound, resetter } = (() => {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    var resetting = document.getElementById("reset");
    return {
        playSound() {
            audio.src = 'sounds/alarm.mp3'
            audio.loop = true;
            audio.play();
        },
        resetter() {
            resetting.addEventListener('click', function () {
                audio.pause();
                audio.loop = false;
                totalShadow.style.display = "none";
                totalShadow.querySelector('.match').style.display = 'none';
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

But keep in mind that this'll still have `playSound` and `resetter` defined on the top level. If you want to avoid that, define *everything* in the IIFE, including the users of `playSound` and `resetter`.